# IE7 check stops page displaying in IE8

Tags: html, css

I have an infuriating issue with IE7 and IE8. An element of my page does not display correctly in IE7, and so after a lot of trial and error I found the simplest fix was to add a conditional part to my page header:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
#slideshow {top: -135px;}
</style>
<![endif]-–>
```

Great! But I find that if I add this to my page, the page will not display *at all* in IE8 - it literally just shows a blank page. If I click the "Quirks" button, the page is displayed.

Anyone any ideas what is going on? It is infuriating.

(IE8.0.6001.18702 on Windows XP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment isn't closed.  The last "dash" character is 0x2013 rather than 0x2D.  Everything following on the page is commented out except for IE7.

Comment: D'oh! You are a superstar, thank you! It won't let me tick your answer yet but I will later.

Comment: Great find LOL. This should be a quiz question :)